# Solr can do the add field and use copy field just don't reindex?

Tags: search, solr

I use the Solr 6.1, 
And i Just completed the document index,
But some reason I need make it not case sensitive in search,
And i found the solution can use copy field make it work,
But it need to add field to help it completed,
Like below :

```
<fieldType name="string_ci" class="solr.TextField"  sortMissingLast="true" omitNorms="true">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>          
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

does anybody know can I use this solution when it completed index after?

or it have other solution can fix it??

Answer (score 1):

No. You'll have to reindex the content (at least the field in question) to change the case of the generated tokens. You can do this either from the original source, or write a script that retrieves each document from Solr and re-indexes the single field - as long as all your fields are set as stored. If they're not stored (and do not have docValues that can be used in place of a stored value), you'll have to reindex. Solr has no way to get the original text from the processed tokens.

Also remember that a KeywordTokenizer will keep the value as a *single token* and not split on whitespace etc.

Make sure you get the correct result before indexing by using the Analysis page under Solr's admin interface.

Comment: I want to use Solr facet feature to calculate the sum but if is 
case is different like "Abc" , "abc", "aBc" but in fact the value it was same in my perception,
so if i want to make it do this I need reindex and it doesn't have other solution right?

Comment: Correct - the facet counts are based on the tokens, and if the tokens are different, they will be separate counts. If you want it to be correct directly from Solr, you'll have to reindex. Unless that's practically hard to do, I'd do that. The other option is to merge the counts in your controller code and create a large filter based on the actual values if its being selected. It's an ugly hack - I'd go with reindexing. Reindexing is something that you'll probably have to do more than once, so make it easy to do.